# get state from render props component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a render props accordion component that does

```
this.props.children({open: this.state.open})
```

in the render()

Then at somewhere else I can use it like so

```
<Accordion>
  {({ open }) => {
    console.log(open) //true or false

    return (
      <>something here</>
    )
  }}
</Accordion>
{open.toString()} //open is not accessible here
```

but how can I access the code outside of the render props function?

Comment: add super(props) in constructor(props) then use this.props.open to check it.

Comment: What's your intention of accessing `open` outside of the render prop? Because it seems like using a render prop, in this case, isn't the best approach.

Comment: @NeiniAmanda storing the ```open``` value in a state using```setState``` inside render props function might do the thing.